# Как правильно склонять слово "мечта"?

Tags: склонение, морфология

Мечта и мечтание(я) - разные вещи. Как правильно сказать например: у меня много (мёчт?). Так вроде нет такого слова.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В русском языке существуют такие понятия: "существительные, имеющие форму только единственного числа (тоска, детство, любовь, молоко и др.)", и "существительные, имеющие форму только мн. ч. (ворота, сани, сумерки)". Слово "мечта" обозначает отвлечённое понятие (абстрактное значение, а не предметное), у него нет род. п. мн. числа. Можно о множественности сказать так: "У меня есть ДВЕ (три, четыре) мечты". ИЛИ заменить синонимичной конструкцией: "Я о многом мечтаю". И, кстати, нужно говорить не "склонить слово", а "склонять"
Согласна со вторым комментарием, спасибо, что не дали саму себя запутать и других ввести в заблуждение. Действительно, слово "мечта" - не одно и то же, что и "тоска". Ну а то, что есть люди, которые употребляют слово "мечт", - их право. Нормы меняются, может, когда-нибудь и "мечт" будет нормой.

Comment: Благодарю за подробный ответ и замечание.

Answer (score 5):

У слова "мечта" лакуна в парадигме. Во множественном числе отсутствует форма для родительного падежа. Но отнюдь не всех форм для множественного числа:
**Мечты, - , мечтам, мечты, мечтами, (о) мечтах.**
Т.е. относить слово к категории Singularia tantum неверно.
При этом Зализняк, например, приводит форму "мечт" для ликвидации этой лакуны. 
==опечатки исправил

Comment: Еще бы знать, что такое "лакуна в парадигме".

Answer (score 1):

Мечта - это большая, недостижимая сейчас цель. Предполагаю, что слово как то связанно со словом мета. Мечт может быть много, как и намеченных целей в жизни.

Мечтание - это действие, когда ты обдумываешь мечту, воображаешь. А мечтания, скорее название для состояний, когда ты мечтаешь.

Comment: *Мета*, т.е. *цель*, Вы имеете в виду? Любопытно. Интересная ассоциация. НО разве в современном русском языке употребляется слово "мета" в смысле "цель"?

В украинском -- да, употребляется. Есть и поисковик такой meta.ua. Насчёт русского -- засомневался.

Comment: Ну как же, а наметить себе дела, планы? По сути - поставить цели. 

Хотят, действительно, заимствованное слово "цель" почти вытеснило слово "мета" из русского. Но это ведь не отменяет его исконного значения.

Answer (score 0):

Я мечтают, они - мечтают, много - мечтаний.

Comment: Смешались в кучу...

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

**Я мечтают, они - мечтают, много - мечтаний.**
Да, вот это правильно! Звучит сразу приятно на слух. А то везде в  последнее время слышно стало коверканье этого романтичного слова в неприятную для слуха словоформу **мечт**.

Например, встретила на одном сайте в форме подписки название одного из статистических счётчиков: "Итого мечт", - ну это же неправильно и некрасиво!

Не лучше было бы написать так: "Итого мечтаний"? Ведь это - другое дело!

Answer (score 0):

Мачта - мачт, почта - почт, мечта - мечт.

> Предписание М. И. Кутузова полевому инспектору почт Западных армий военному советнику Ф. О. Доливо-Добровольскому. М. И. Кутузов. Документы (1812)

> кроме двух мачт на нем ничего нет. Ушаков.

Хотя Белинский против:

> Третий пункт — незнание русского языка; за этот аргумент ухватились даже те, которые пишут: морь (вместо морей), мозгов человеческих, **мечт** и т. п.

А вот рассуждение Аксакова:

> Сюда собственно относятся действия непроизвольные, необходимо вытекающие из своей причины, действия естественные, действия природы, напр. вода течет, огонь горит, птица летит, рыба плывет. Здесь действие схвачено, как состояние, вытекающее из существа предмета. ― Сюда относятся также действия, хотя не выражающие состояния, хотя и произвольные, но длительные или общие по смыслу своему, напр. люблю, верю и проч. Мы сказали, что всякое действие первоначально представляется в этом виде и выражается в языке тематическою формою: это справедливо; но действие, как понятие, производное из других понятий, не имеющее в себе первоначального действительного характера, ― производное в то же время и в языке, как слово, ― может вовсе не иметь в глаголе этой тематической формы, напр. дум-а-ю, мечт-а-ю. Мы должны присоединить еще нужное замечание. Всякое естественное действие является в этом первом виде, т. - е. как неопределенно-сущее, и всякий глагол получает в языке форму тематическую; но значение самого действия изменяет самое значение формы. Как скоро действие не вытекает из свойства предмета, не есть его состояние, как скоро оно случайно или произвольно, как скоро также не имеет оно в себе длительность, и в то же время не отвлеченно, а живо; то понятное в явлении и выраженное через тему, как напр. паду, сяду, ― действие уже не может быть неопределенным по смыслу своему, и переходя в действительность, сейчас определяется как момент и получает значение действия однократного, а в следствие того употребляется в будущем.

Мечта и мечтание - разные?

Ну морь - криво кончено, но есть, например, вода - вод (множественное число), вполне употребимое. Возможно мечта - это метка, картинка, а мечтание - это процесс, семантически несовместимые вещи.

Мечт - когда мечта объект, сленговое словечко, в то в время как мечта образец от мечтание.

Также как вера. Однако, вера вполне себе сокращают до объективной веры, символов веры - разных вер. Хотя вера - это не объекты, а процесс поиска истины. И тут есть вопрос с подвохом: Ты в Бога веришь? В - Бог - объект. Можно *верить Богу*, но не *в Бога*. **Верить - искать, процесс поиска.**

Однако примеров со множественным числом слова вера - вер масса:

> Разве тем, что по вашему ж речению, из суеверства расколы возрастают, то мню, что разность вер в государстве вред наносит? Татищев.

Так что граница понятия есть, но говорят и так и сяк. Однако, **мечт** - исторически порицаемо, видимо, из-за авторитета Белинского.

> Конные, пешие, артиллеристы, **люди разных вер** и народов, схватывались толпами, в одиночку, резались, боролись и дрались на смерть!

Или вот Тредьяковский:

> да и самая безопасность, в рассуждении будущего века, повелевает лучше верить< в> бога, нежели не верить.

Корректор, молодец, поправил, "в" поставил) Верить бога ну никак у него не клеилось. Любить бога можно, а верить бога не можно)

Верить от verify - проверять, сверять, пытать. Так что я, наверное, буду говорить не *верить в дружбу*, а **верить дружбу**, **верить идеал**, **верить пользу**, **верить мечту**.

А ты, веришь мечту?